# От чего зависит плавность сайтов?

Tags: javascript, html, css

От чего зависит плавность сайтов? Имею в виду разные эфекты появления меню, слайдеры, скроллы и тп. 
Сделал меню, на пк проверяю все нормально, плавно, красиво. Но, когда дело доходит до проверки на моб. устройствах мне становится стыдно. Все рывками, дергается, непонятно как смещается и тп. Даже обычный скролл тупит.

Подскажите, как правильно делать плавную верстку, от чего это зависит(css свойства и тп), какие есть подводные камни?

P.S. Пример моего меню

```js
$('.trigger-menu').on('click', function () {
      $('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
    });
    $('.bg').on('click', function () {
      $("#mobile-menu-trigger:checked,.menu-inner-trigger:checked").prop("checked", false).change();
      $('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
    });
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px; }

.mobile-menu {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: -webkit-transform .4s ease;
  transition: transform .4s ease;
  transition: transform .4s ease, -webkit-transform .4s ease;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-102%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-102%, 0, 0);
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  box-shadow: 3px 0 4px lightgrey; }
  .mobile-menu__header {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff4081;
    background: #fff; }
  .mobile-menu__logo-wrapper {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto; }
  .mobile-menu__list {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; }
  .mobile-menu__item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey; }
  .mobile-menu__link {
    padding: 5px;
    display: block; }
  .mobile-menu__inner {
    background: #f78a8a;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: -webkit-transform .4s ease;
    transition: transform .4s ease;
    transition: transform .4s ease, -webkit-transform .4s ease;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0); }

#mobile-menu-trigger:checked + .mobile-menu {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }

input[data-menu="menu"]:checked + .mobile-menu__inner {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }

.display-hidden {
  display: none; }

.trigger-menu {
  background: #91a2f7;
  float: right; }

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s; }

.menu-open .bg {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible; }

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto; }

.menu-back-trigger {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff4081; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

    <label class="trigger-menu" for="mobile-menu-trigger">Trigger</label>
    <input id="mobile-menu-trigger" class="display-hidden" type="checkbox">
    <nav class="mobile-menu">
      <header class="mobile-menu__header">
        <div class="mobile-menu__logo-wrapper">
          <img class="logo" src="http://placehold.it/150x30">
        </div>
      </header>
      <ul class="mobile-menu__list">
        <li class="mobile-menu__item">
          <label class="mobile-menu__link" for="menu-inner-trigger-1">Category</label>
          <input id="menu-inner-trigger-1" class="menu-inner-trigger display-hidden" type="checkbox" data-menu="menu">
          <div class="mobile-menu__inner">
            <label class="mobile-menu__link menu-back-trigger" for="menu-inner-trigger-1">Category</label>
            <ul class="mobile-menu__inner-list">
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category2
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category3
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category4
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category5
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="mobile-menu__item">
          <label class="mobile-menu__link" for="menu-inner-trigger-2">Category2</label>
          <input id="menu-inner-trigger-2" class="menu-inner-trigger display-hidden" type="checkbox" data-menu="menu">
          <div class="mobile-menu__inner">
            <label class="mobile-menu__link" for="menu-inner-trigger-2">Category2</label>
            <ul class="mobile-menu__inner-list">
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category2
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category3
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category4
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="mobile-menu__inner-item">
                <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
                  Inner category5
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="mobile-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
            Delivery
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="mobile-menu__item">
          <a href="#" class="mobile-menu__link">
            About
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="bg"></div>
```

Comment: может телефон слабый?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, Мой BB Z10, может и слаб, хотя мало вероятно, там проблема в браузере, хотя в других браузерах меньше, но таже проблема. А вот в iPhone 6 и 6s наблюдается таже беда, но в меньших маштабах

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этой очень легкой задачке, как выдвижное меню, слишком сложная реализация.
Ты просто перегружаешь браузер ненужной работой, ни тебе, ни ему.
Зачем `translate3d`, если идет работа с чистейшим 2Д?
Я бегло посмотрел, но вероятно, вложенность тегов не учитывает слои для прорисовки браузером, а они, в  свою очередь, плохо заданы css свойствами.
Я советую покапать в сети о том, как браузер прорисовывает анимацию, что лучше использовать `transition` или `animation` и в каких случаях.
Даже если эффект достигается один и тот же, зачастую два разных свойства оказывают неравный след на производительности.
У меня есть такой пример: я пытался сделать тень на градиентном элементе. Дело в том, что `text-shadow` рисуется поверх градиента (`background-color: linear-gradient`). И это можно обойти двумя путями, в основном теге отрисовывать тень с помощью `text-shadow`, а в псевдоклассе рисовать градиентный текст. Этот вариант я и выбрал, сейчас расскажу почему. Либо же использовать `filter: drop-shadow`. И тут уже встает логический вопрос, по простой внутренней логике понятно, ведь чтобы нарисовать простенькую тень, не хотелось бы использовать фильтр. Почему? Если при этом ещё использовать `transform: scale`, то браузер каждый кадр этого скейла будет отрисовывать новый фильтр. А это затратно и на самом деле на моем стационарном компе, в Хроме, начинало подлагивать такое появление, хотя анимация шла `80ms`, то есть быстрее чем среднее моргание человека. 
Так что вывод такой: нужно отрисовывать в голове и понимать, как рисует это всё браузер, не использовать навороченные свойства в сторону их силы, а посмотреть на простенькие, но эффективные в связке css-свойства.

Comment: Пожалуйста, обьясните, что вы имеете ввиду "Я бегло посмотрел, но вероятно, вложенность тегов не учитывает слои для прорисовки браузером, а они, в свою очередь, плохо заданы css свойствами."

Comment: @AFI19, дело в том, что браузеру иногда чтобы отрисовать вложенный элемент, перед этим нужно отрисовать все остальные элементы заного. Чем меньше вложенность, тем лучше для анимации. Далее я советовал узнать про отрисовку браузером содержимого и анимацию в частности, это вот оно и есть.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос слишком общий, так как это может зависеть от алгоритма, используемого при анимации(например, движение в 1000 итераций по 1 пикселю будет больше, чем в 2 раза хуже по времени и русурсам цп, чем движение в 500 итераций по 2 пикселя), тактовая частота процессора(у мобильных устройств она обычно ниже), даже частота видеокарты и даже конкретный движок, обрабатывающий JS\CSS(в разных браузерах он разный, хотя уже вроде намечается консенсус в этом отношении в среде производителей браузеров)

Answer (score 0):

Твоем меню слишком сложное. Сделай вложенность меньше. Откажись от списка. Сделай `nav` и в нем `a`. Также обнови jQuery до 3.1.1